# QT [install_target]Error 1(ignored)

Tags: qt

I am a newbie to Qt. Just started with Qt development. After properly linking SDK and NDK for Android development, when I tried to run Hello World application, I got an error `[install_target]Error 1(ignored)`.

Here is the log:

```
22:56:08: Running steps for project HelloWorld...
22:56:08: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
22:56:08: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
22:56:08: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
22:56:08: Removing directory /home/vijay/Documents/Android Applications/HelloWorld/android-build
22:56:08: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 'INSTALL_ROOT=/home/vijay/Documents/Android Applications/HelloWorld/android-build' install
/bin/sh: 1: test: /home/vijay/Documents/Android: unexpected operator
install -m 755 -p "libHelloWorld.so" "/home/vijay/Documents/Android Applications/HelloWorld/android-build/libs/armeabi/libHelloWorld.so"
install: cannot create regular file '/home/vijay/Documents/Android Applications/HelloWorld/android-build/libs/armeabi/libHelloWorld.so': No such file or directory
Makefile:1722: recipe for target 'install_target' failed
make: [install_target] Error 1 (ignored)
22:56:08: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
22:56:08: Starting: "/home/vijay/Qt5.4.1/5.4/android_armv5/bin/androiddeployqt" --input '/home/vijay/Documents/Android Applications/HelloWorld/android-libHelloWorld.so-deployment-settings.json' --output '/home/vijay/Documents/Android Applications/HelloWorld/android-build' --deployment bundled --android-platform android-22 --jdk /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64 --ant /usr/bin/ant
Application binary is not in output directory: /home/vijay/Documents/Android Applications/HelloWorld/android-build//libs/armeabi/libHelloWorld.so. Please run 'make install INSTALL_ROOT=/home/vijay/Documents/Android Applications/HelloWorld/android-build/' first.
Generating Android Package
  Input file: /home/vijay/Documents/Android Applications/HelloWorld/android-libHelloWorld.so-deployment-settings.json
  Output directory: /home/vijay/Documents/Android Applications/HelloWorld/android-build/
  Application binary: /home/vijay/Documents/Android Applications/HelloWorld/libHelloWorld.so
  Android build platform: android-22
  Install to device: No
22:56:08: The process "/home/vijay/Qt5.4.1/5.4/android_armv5/bin/androiddeployqt" exited with code 7.
**Error while building/deploying project HelloWorld (kit: Android for armeabi (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.4.1))
When executing step "Build Android APK"**
22:56:08: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

Kindly help me to resolve. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you provide more information, lets say a log or something?

Comment: I have added log in the question

Comment: You could paste the logs as code - in this way its quite hard to read them.. have you read this? http://wiki.qt.io/Android

Comment: `/bin/sh: 1: test: /home/vijay/Documents/Android: unexpected operator` You need to find what's causing this shell script failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the answer:  I had included a space in my output directory.  Evidently one of the commands couldn't handle that, and thus the error.  I renamed the directory and then it worked.